# Не выводит изображение в bootstrap select React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap

Всем доброго вечера. Хотел сделать смену языка с помощью bootstrap select, но когда я вставляю в него иконку отображается вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
import ruIcon from 'path';

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <select className="custom-select">
        <option value="0">
          <img src={ruIcon} alt="" />
          <span>Ru</span>
        </option>
        <option value="1">En</option>
        <option value="2">Ua</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Но если я попытаюсь вывести картинку вне select, то все верно работает. Почему не отображается картинка, а некий "[object, Object]" и как это исправить?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Судя по их [примерам](https://thdoan.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples.html), картинки можно вставлять следующим образом (через аттрибут `data-thumbnail`):

```
<select title="Select your surfboard" class="selectpicker">
  <option>Select...</option>
  <option data-thumbnail="images/icon-chrome.png">Chrome</option>
  <option data-thumbnail="images/icon-firefox.png">Firefox</option>
  <option data-thumbnail="images/icon-ie.png">IE</option>
  <option data-thumbnail="images/icon-opera.png">Opera</option>
  <option data-thumbnail="images/icon-safari.png">Safari</option>
</select>
```

По крайней мере это очень похоже на то что вам нужно